# How to reference the element id in VUE :class

Tags: css, vue.js

I have several divs, which I'm not going to put in v-for, but still need to unique reference them. For @click id attribute works well.

```
<div v-bind:class="setAreaStyle('CAR')" @click="setFocus($event)" id="CAR">
```

But is there a way I can use element id, **without click event**, as reference in called function, so setAreaStyle would received 'CAR' as argument?

```
<div v-bind:class="setAreaStyle(id)" id="CAR">
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$event.target.id`

```html
<div :class="setAreaStyle($event.target.id)" 
  @click="setFocus($event)" 
  id="CAR"
>
```

Comment: What about the same situation, but without clikc event?
<div v-bind:class="setAreaStyle(id)"  id="CAR">

Comment: Something like `:class="setFocus(item.$el.id)"` (don't quote me on the exact syntax here)? Again, you could probably pass that id as a prop to the element, but you can use this syntax too if you want to spend time going back and forth in your DOM/state. TLDR: I do not recommend. The other answer is better overall. @JanisJakaitis

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `id` you'll use will come from the `v-for` item, no ? You can then use it in both places:

```html
<div
  v-for="item in items"
  :key="item.id"
  :class="setAreaStyle(item.id)"
  :id="item.id"
  @click="setFocus($event)"
>
```

Side note: the name `setAreaStyle` is strange (seems it will do some side effects), you should only `get` something here, and it is the class name => `getClass` would make more sense.
Or `:style="getStyle(item.id)"` if you want to add inline CSS

Comment: Yep, pretty much this one. No need to do anything special.